# Background color behind a variable or keywords

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

In Android Studio, i am unable to understand the meaning of background color of keywords or variables.
I've joined a picture in order to get a better idea.

1) the String variable "day" don't have any background color at the declaration and also inside the constructor.

2) The String variable "descriptionSummary" have a brown background color at the declaration but not in the constructor, why?

3) Why the keywords "public" have a brown background color?

I really don't understand the meaning and also i would like to change these colors, so thank you for the help.

Comment: You can hover over each occurrence and it'll tell you why it's highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hover over them to find out, but if I had to guess

1. `day` is fine. So is everything else not highlighted
2. `descriptionSummary` is initialized, but never used
3. You never used that constructor anywhere in your code, or it can be package-private (personally, I turned off that message on my IDE)

You've searched for `getDescription`, so it's green

You can change the theme of the IDE. Not sure how much control you get over those colors

Comment: Thank you cricket_007.

1) Fine.
2) You're right, it's a mistake. in fact i use the function but not this variable  so i've removed it.
an3) The constructor is not used in this class but i instanciate an object of this class in another class so, the constructor is called.

Comment: **That** particular constructor needs to be called. Not just `new WeatherObject()`

Comment: Thanks again.
I need a precision and sorry for my lack of experience but in another class (the on who i instanciate a WeatherObject, i do it like this:

    weatherWeekList.add(new WeatherObject(weatherDay, weatherCity, weatherTempMin, weatherTempMax, weatherIcon, weatherDescription));    


So what is the problem?

Comment: Not sure. Like I said, it's a guess. What's the hover over say on the highlight?

Comment: access can be package private

Comment: i wrote private before package at the beginin of the class and all the public functions now have no brown background color.
Now, it is another thing but why should i make the package private?
So i go back to default and going to emove private.

Comment: Package private and `private` are two different things. Package private is the lack of either `public` or `private` on the constructor definition

Answer (score 0):

The Android studio gives you suggestions to improve the code. For example, `public` can be turned into a package-private access. Hover over the highlighted text, and you'll see a light bulb and explanation like shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz.
I learned in OOP that evrything can be private must be private.
It is stupid but in my courses i've never seen private package, just package.
so thank you.

Comment: I mean package-private as described in Java Controlling Access to Members of a Class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. It means you can remove public.

Answer (score -1):

1. **day** is not highlighted
2. the colour of **descriptionsummary** will change when you will use that in program

   I dont think that we can change these colours because its predifined by android studio. We can change only theme if we want.